# Dynamically-generated Javascript within HAML

Tags: javascript, ruby, haml

Why doesn't this work?

```
:javascript
    -[1,2,3].each do |number|
        $("#form_#{number}").my_method();
```

Rails gives me an error, saying that the variable `number` isn't defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The content of a filter isn’t interpreted as Haml. You can use `#{...}` for interpolation though, and that’s why you’re seeing the error – the filter sees the `#{number}` in `"#form_#{number}"`, but the line above where `number` is defined is simply passed through as it is, not treated as Ruby, so as far as Ruby is concerned `number` is still undefined.

In this case you could do something like:

```
:javascript
    #{[1,2,3].map do |number|
        "$(\"#form_#{number}\").my_method();"
    end.join("\n")}
```

although that’s a bit unwieldy.

A clearer solution might be to create a helper method to create the javascript, which you could call from the filter:

```ruby
def create_js(arr)
  arr.map do |number|
      "$(\"#form_#{number}\").my_method();"
  end.join("\n")
end
```

and the Haml would be

```
:javascript
    #{create_js([1,2,3])}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! Works well, except I wasn't able to get the `.join("\n")` trick to work on ruby 1.9.3 (the function above just returns the contents of `arr`)

Comment: @bevanb note I changed `each` to `map` as well as add the `join`; did you change that too? Otherwise, what do you see? (I’m using 1.9.3 and it works for me).

Comment: Ah, I missed the change from `each` to `map`, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You have ruby syntax within your javascript and that obviously will not work.  You can use a library like underscore.js and iterate over your array like this:

```
_.each([1, 2, 3], function(number){
    $("#form_" + number).my_method();
});
```

Try that.

Or you can use jQuery's each:

```
$.each([1, 2, 3], function(i, number){
     $("#form_" + number).my_method();
});
```

Comment: Or, if the `$()` indicates jQuery, `$.each([1,2,3],function(i, number) {...`